# Use CollectionType inside my ThreadType on Symfony display a field for each message, not only the first

Tags: forms, symfony, nested-forms

```
<?php

class ThreadType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextareaType::class, [
                'attr' => [
                    'class' => 'froala-form-title'
                ]
            ])
            ->add('messages', CollectionType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                'entry_type' => MessageType::class,
                'entry_options' => [
                    'label' => false
                ],
            ]);
    }
    // ...
```

My form for create a new Thread is OK, I have my thread title field and the message field:

[image]

After that, I add multiple messages inside my thread, and when I want edit my Thread I have this problem:

[image]

My CollectionType field display one textarea by messages inside my thread, I only want edit the first message, how can I perform that on Symfony?

Comment: I would probably restructure this, since you apparently don't want to primarily edit the thread, but the first post and the thread title, and *display* the other posts. CollectionType is meant to handle multiple form of identical type, you can't easily remove "one" form from the collection or handle it differently, your form would need some kind of form event listener and react to which post is supposed to be editable, but that's a pretty frickle design.

Comment: I don't want display the other posts. On my last screenshot, I only want display the title field and the first message field. But CollectionType don't allow me to filter my thread messages for only select the first, CollectionType return all messages and not only the first, that is the problem.

Comment: As I said, make a form type for the (first) post (MessageType), and display additional stuff you want to display. Handling this via ThreadType isn't particularly logical, since you apparently don't want to modify the thread but the post/message. this looks very javascripty, so I would probably load the edit form for a message in place of the message anyway. so ... make a post-edit form and not a thread-edit form. ;o)

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this code:

```
    $firstThreadMessage = $options['data']->getMessages()[0];

    $builder
        ->add('title', TextareaType::class, [
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'froala-form-title'
            ]
        ])
        ->add('messages', MessageType::class, [
            'mapped' => false,
            'data' => $firstThreadMessage
        ])
    ;
```

For this formType $options['data'] is my Thread, I can easy get the first message of the thread with ->getMessages()[0];. mapped is false here but is handled by the MessageType class.